# ErrorException : Undefined offset: 0 in laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

This is the line am getting error.
 `$Notify = $this->value('NOTIFY')[0][0]['value1'];`

where value is another function as

```
public function value($type)
{
   
    $arrs = DB::table('notice')->where('code', $type)
    ->where('flg', '0')
    ->get();
    $arr=array();
    foreach ($arrs as $one) {
        $arr[]=array('code'=>$one->code,'value1'=>$one->txt);
    }
    return array($arr);
}
```

how I can get value1 ?

Comment: If you return `return $arr;` instead of adding an extra unnecessary array by returning `return array($arr);` it may be easier to address. Then use `$this->value('NOTIFY')[0]['value1'];` **Always assuming that you have at least one result in the array**

Comment: I tried using just return $arr; it didnt worked for me.

Comment: SO do a `var_dump($this->value('NOTIFY'))` to see what being returned

Comment: its returning array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: Then it looks like like your query returned nothing. You may need to code for that possibility

Comment: but db table have value for that column

Comment: Look at a `dd($arrs)` after the `->get()` is there rows returned?